# how can i recover password of my local websphere server?

Tags: websphere, password

I forot password for wasadmin.So am not able to enter into admin pane.I want to recover the password.Where is encoded passwod located?How can i decode it?I am using same password at many other places,so i want recover password rather then resetting password.

Answer (score 2):

http://robertmaldon.blogspot.com/2006/07/recovering-passwords-from-websphere.html

This link might help you...

Comment: it's too old , only works for xor type , which does not work for WAS 7 or higher version

Answer (score 2):

Recover Password in Websphere

```
Step 1: Open up your console and navigate to the folder that contains "ws_runtime.jar". Use a search tool to find it.

Step 2: java -cp ws_runtime.jar com.ibm.ws.security.util.PasswordEncoder "password"

Example:

Input

java -cp ws_runtime.jar com.ibm.ws.security.util.PasswordEncoder "password"

Output

decoded password == "password", encoded password == "{xor}Lz4sLCgwLTs="
```

Decode your password in Websphere

```
Step 1: Location and open "security.xml". It will be folder with a similar path like so "runtime\..?..\PROFILE_ACCOUNT\...?..\workspace\..?..\". Use a search tool to find it.

Step 2: In "security.xml", find the "authDataEntries" tag and then get the password attribute.

Step 3: Open up your console and navigate to the folder that contains "ws_runtime.jar". Use a search tool to find it.

Step 4: java -cp ws_runtime.jar com.ibm.ws.security.util.PasswordDecoder PASSWORD_ATTIBUTE

Example:

Input

java -cp ws_runtime.jar com.ibm.ws.security.util.PasswordDecoder {xor}Lz4sLCgwLTs=

Output

encoded password == "{xor}Lz4sLCgwLTs=", decoded password == "password"
```

This might help...